# Saving sensitive data securely in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app in which I need to save an array of type [Card], where card is the struct:

```
struct Card : {
    var image : UIImage? = nil
    var name : String = ""
    var titles : [String] = []
    var data : [String] = []
}
```

What is the best way to persist this array considering that it contains data such as credit card numbers?

Would it be enough to enable `Data Protection` under the `Capabilities` tab in XCode? At the moment I'm saving using Codable.

Comment: You shouldn't save any sensitive data on the device.

Comment: WHY do you need this data? Handling credit card information is a BAD idea unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @ShamasS why? Is it more "secure" on the web / in the cloud?

Comment: @luk2302 I would assume so.

Comment: In you absolutely need to save sensitive data on your device, make sure it's encrypted. To make sure the encryption key is unreachable, use CommonCrypto and 256 bit elliptic curve key. That ensures that the key will never leave the Secure Enclave of your device

Comment: Before you even think about storing credit card numbers you need to understand PCI-DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard

Comment: @Redox as luk2302 said, storing cc information in the local is not recommended even in the keychain. though you passing/storing the information to the cloud should be more secure in encrypted way. if you are using AWS cloud then go for KMS otherwise you can use AES 256 alog to encrypt your end and store it into DB.. Make sure you need to handle PCI before storing all cc data in your backend. one question you need ans for why do you need to store the cc data in your local device?

Comment: @Shamas S Sensitive data is not necessarily more secure in the cloud than on a device. Devices can be lost but most data breaches occur with data stored in the cloud. A large database of credit card numbers is a much more attractive target than a single persons credit card information stored on a device. Also, it is quite difficult to recover data from a properly secured iOS device (according to the FBI at least).  That said any iOS app storing sensitive information  should have it's own layer of security above that offered by the device  including it's own user authentication process.

Comment: @AndrewDGrant Hi Andrew, That's a very well written response. And I agree with absolutely everything that you said. I think you should post it as an answer down below (I will definitely upvote it.) My only point was that devices can be jailbroken into as well. If it were up to me, I would pass the buck to someone 3rd party that's already done this. :) Again, thank you for a very constructive response. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no right answer to this, but it's a great way to see how much a person has dug into iOS security. If you're interviewing with a bank I'd almost definitely expect someone to know something about it, but all companies need to take security seriously, so here's the ideal list of topics I'd expect to hear in an answer:

- If the data is extremely sensitive then it should never be stored offline on the device because all devices are crackable.
- The keychain is one option for storing data securely. However it's encryption is based on the pin code of the device. User's are not forced to set a pin, so in some situations the data may not even be encrypted. In addition the users pin code may be easily hacked.
- A better solution is to use something like **SQLCipher** which is a fully encrypted SQLite database. The encryption key can be enforced by the application and separate from the user's pin code.
  Other security best practices are:
- Only communicate with remote servers over SSL/HTTPS.
- If possible implement certificate pinning in the application to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks on public WiFi.
- Clear sensitive data out of memory by overwriting it.
- Ensure all validation of data being submitted is also run on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Sensitive data is not necessarily more secure in the cloud than on a device. Devices can be lost but most data breaches occur with data stored in the cloud. A large database of credit card numbers is a much more attractive target than a single persons credit card information stored on a device. Also, it is quite difficult to recover data from a properly secured iOS device (according to the FBI at least).

That said, any iOS app storing sensitive information should have it's own layer of security above that offered by the device including it's own user authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the numerous reasons not to do this, a good way to securely store local data on iOS is trough the Keychain. It's encrypted with your passcode by the device, is preserved for your app even if it is un-installed, and syncs between devices. The API is kind of hard to understand for beginners, so a wrapper such as https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess is a good tool to get started.

Answer (score -1):

In Order to save our apps sensitive data, we should use **Security services** provided by **Apple**.

**Keychain Services API** helps you solve these problems by giving your app a way to store the small amount of user data in an encrypted database called the keychain.
In the keychain, you are free to save passwords and other secrets that the user explicitly cares about, such as credit card information or even short sensitive notes.

You can refer [this link](https://medium.com/swift2go/application-security-musts-for-every-ios-app-dabf095b9c4f) for a detailed description of using Keychain Services API.

Comment: What do you mean by short sensitive notes?

Comment: I think Keychain Service's encryption is based on the device pin code, sometimes the data may not be secure, That's why never use bank card numbers in the keychain.